# Click through window, XSendEvent is not working properly

Tags: c++, x11, xlib

I am trying to make a click through window. So I assume I need to pass XButtonEvents to the window directly under mine. It is selecting the right window however when running xev on the window that should receive the xevent it doesnt detect anything.
UPDATE:
So xev still reports nothing however it grabs the window I release it over. It will not click buttons however.

```
XButtonEvent createButtonEvent(Display *dp, Window win, bool press){
        Window parent, rootwin, dischild;
        rootwin = DefaultRootWindow(dp);
        Window *child;
        unsigned int numberChildern;
        int px, py, i, rx, ry; 
        XWindowAttributes childAttr;
        XButtonEvent buttonEvent;
        buttonEvent.type=press?ButtonPress:ButtonRelease;
        buttonEvent.send_event=false;
        buttonEvent.display=dp;
        buttonEvent.root=rootwin;
        buttonEvent.subwindow=None;
        buttonEvent.state=Button1Mask;
        buttonEvent.same_screen=true;
        XQueryTree(dp, rootwin, &rootwin, &parent, &child, &numberChildern);

        px=0;
        py=0;
        if(!XQueryPointer(dp, rootwin, &buttonEvent.root, &dischild,
                &px, &py, &rx, &ry, &buttonEvent.state))
                {   
                fprintf(stderr, "Error cound not query pointer");
                return buttonEvent;
                }   

        for(i=0; i<numberChildern; i++)
        {   
                if(child[i]==win)continue;
                XGetWindowAttributes(dp, child[i], &childAttr);    
                if((px<childAttr.x)||(py<childAttr.y)||(px>(childAttr.x+childAttr.width))
                        ||(py>(childAttr.y+childAttr.height)))continue;
                else{
                buttonEvent.x_root=rx;
                buttonEvent.y_root=ry;
                buttonEvent.x=px-childAttr.x;
                buttonEvent.y=py-childAttr.y;
                buttonEvent.window=child[i];
                fprintf(stderr,"%d x=%d,y=%d,px=%d,py=%d\n",i,childAttr.x,childAttr.y,px,py);
                return buttonEvent;
                }   
}
                return buttonEvent;
}
```

Then I call and send as follows:

```
    buttonPress=createButtonEvent(dp, win, true);
    buttonRelease=createButtonEvent(dp, win, false);
    XSendEvent(dp, buttonPress.window, true, ButtonPressMask, (XEvent *)&buttonPress);
    XSendEvent(dp, buttonRelease.window, true, ButtonReleaseMask, (XEvent *)&buttonRelease);
```

Comment: Many X11 programs ignore user-sent events for security reasons. That's probably not your immediate problem, just something to be aware of.

Comment: I'm assuming that is not the issue because the window boarder will accept the button press and move or change size (depending on if its the top border or one of the others). Thus it does respond to the event, it's just not the window specified nor the pixel or location specified.

Comment: The border most is probably a different window, not the one you want to send events to. The window manager creates borders and it may do so by reparenting the window you want, such that it is no longer an immediate child of the root window. You may need a recursive `XQueryTree` in order to find the youngest-generation window. You may also need to sort same-level siblings by the Z stacking order, and go through the list from the topmost to the bottommost.

Comment: I do not think the border is a different window because I have it print out all the coordinates of the windows it finds in from XQueryTree and it the borders were separate windows there would be double entries. Also the array of children it returns is in Z order, bottom most first.

Comment: No there will be no double entries. Actual windows are not children of the root, they are children of their decoration windows. You need to do the recursive query anyway because a program may not watch its top level window. Instead, it may use some descendant(s) of it for event processing.